# Makefile with multiple inputs and outputs

Tags: r, makefile

I'm wanting to use a makefile to update figure files generated by R code. The R code is in various files in the directory `../R` and all ending in `.R`. The figure files are in the directory `../figs` and all ending in `.pdf` or `.png`. If an R file has a later date than any of the figure files, I want to process the R file with the command

```
R --no-save < file.R
```

I've looked a various example makefiles but couldn't find anything I could adapt.

My current effort (not working) is as follows:

```
PLOTDIR= ../figs
RDIR= ../R
RFILES= $(RDIR)/*.R
PLOTS= *.pdf *.png
FIGURES= $(PLOTDIR)/$(PLOTS)
$(FIGURES): $(RFILES)
    R --no-save < $<
```

Comment: Why don't you use `Rscript file.R` instead of `R --no-save < file.R`?

Comment: Is there any connection between the names of the R files and the names of the figure files?

Comment: @rinni. No special reason. That would work as well.

Comment: @Beta. No. One R file can create many different figure files with arbitrary names.

Comment: If Make is annoying you, try Scons http://www.scons.org/ - you'll be starting from scratch but its a much more "regular" replacement for Make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following.

The tricks are that you need to deduce output from inputs (.R file)

```
# Makefile
# Beware of indentation when copying use TABS

PLOTDIR = ../figs
RDIR = ../R

# list R files
RFILES = $(wildcard $(RDIR)/*.R)

# compute output file names
PDF_FIGS = $(RFILES:.R=.pdf)
PNG_FIGS = $(RFILES:.R=.png)

# relocate files in output folder
OUT_FILES = $(subst $(RDIR), $(PLOTDIR), $(PDF_FIGS) $(PNG_FIGS))

# first target is the default: simply do 'make'
all: $(OUT_FILES)

clean:
    rm $(OUT_FILES)

.PHONY: all clean

# need to split PNG from PDF rules
$(PLOTDIR)/%.png: $(RDIR)/%.R
    R --no-save < $<

$(PLOTDIR)/%.pdf $(PLOTDIR)/%.png: $(RDIR)/%.R
    R --no-save < $<
```

**Edit** to reflect my comment: Use 1 dependency output file per R script

```
PLOTDIR= ../figs
RDIR= ../R

# list R files
RFILES := $(wildcard $(RDIR)/*.R)

# relocate files in output folder
OUT_FILES=$(subst $(RDIR), $(PLOTDIR), $(RFILES:.R=.out))
#$(warning $(OUT_FILES))

# first target is the default: simply do 'make'
all: $(OUT_FILES)

clean:
    rm $(OUT_FILES)

.PHONY: all clean

$(PLOTDIR)/%.out: $(RDIR)/%.R
    R --no-save < $< && touch $@
```

Comment: I don't think this will work. The names of the `OUT_FILES` are incorrect, so it will, in general, run every R file every time.

Comment: @Beat: I fixed the rules. Only subsisting problem is that we don't know if a PDF or PNG is issued (or both). One solution is to create only one output file (i.e  ../figs/%.out) from one R script using 'touch' (plus really generating figure file, of course).

Comment: Thanks. Your second file did exactly what I needed, even though it wasn't exactly what I asked for!

Answer (score 1):

An interesting problem. It's logically simple, but goes right against the grain of what Make likes to do.

This seems to work. It relies on an obscure feature of pattern rules: if a pattern rule has more than one target, Make infers that it need be run only once to update all of its targets.

```
PLOTDIR = ../figs
RDIR = ../R
RFILES = $(wildcard $(RDIR)/*.R)
FIGURES = $(wildcard $(PLOTDIR)/*.pdf $(PLOTDIR)/*.png)

all: $(FIGURES)

$(PLOTDIR)/%.pdf $(PLOTDIR)/%.png: $(RFILES)
        @for x in $?; do R --no-save \< $$x; done
```

Comment: That does what I want (with the \< replaced by <). However, it reveals a logic problem with my idea. If file1.R produces a.pdf and file2.R produces b.pdf, then when file2.R is updated, make will always try to run it because a.pdf is older and remains so. I guess I will need to specify which R files correspond to which pdf/png files.

Comment: @Beta: what if no figure already exists ? FIGURES is empty and nothing is done.

Comment: @RobHyndman To have finer-grained control over which .R files generate which figures, you can separate the prereqs declaration from the recipe declaration. To do this, use a generic recipe (i.e., remove $(RFILES) from the recipe here) to do the work, and the prereqs for each target (figure) can be on declaration lines w/o a recipe. Hm; not sure if that will work with the $? automatic variable; it might.

Comment: @levif, you're right, I hadn't thought of that. There are ways to correct it, but it looks as if the question itself is obsolete.